# Google Play Store App publich pre-launch report

Tags: java, android, android-studio

when I published my app, the pre-launch report always keep showing this warning?

Consider increasing this item's text foreground to background contrast ratio.
The item's text contrast ratio is 3.67. This ratio is based on a text color of #FFFFFF and background color of #568AB7. Consider increasing this item's text contrast ratio to 4.50 or greater.

But I have no idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the colors to more contrast ones. You can change the backround color to a more darker blue, for example `#0A3E6B`